# OpenCV for Android with NEON

Tags: opencv, android

I did not understand version of OpenCV 3 or 3.1 for Android already includes an extension for NEON? It will be used automatically? Or I need to compile the source code for NEON by myself? Where to get a good manual about it, or already builded project?

Comment: seems that not included?